# Complement of regular language is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

**The Question**

Let $L$ be a regular language. Prove the $\overline{L}$ is a regular language ***without using automata***.

**Explanation**

I have an assignment to solve **without using automata at all**. To solve one of the questions I want to use the following: "If $L_1$, $L_2$ are regular languages, then $L_1\bigcap L_2$ is a regular language". The properties allowed to use are listed in "Allowed to use only".

So I thought of using De Morgan's law: $L_1\bigcap L_2$ = $\overline{\overline {L_1}\bigcup \overline{L_2}}$
But complement is not one of the properties allowed to use. If you can show the intersection is a regular without complement and without automata that would be good as well.

**Allowed to use only**

- **Alphabet** $\Sigma$ set of symbols, final.
- **Word** $w$ finite
  concatenation of symbols from $\Sigma$ and final.
- **Sigma Kleene star** $\Sigma ^*$ all words with symbols from $\Sigma$ including $\varepsilon$ the empty string.
- **Language** $L$ subset of $\Sigma ^*$.
- Let $L$ $M$ be languages under $\Sigma$. Then $L\bigcup M$, $L\bigcap M$, $L\circ M$, $\overline{L}$, $\overline{M}$, are also languages under $\Sigma$.
- Language $L$ is **regular**, if there exists a regex r, that is a string under $\Sigma \bigcup $ {$ ∅, \circ, *, \bigcup $}, which defines $L$.

  1. If $L_1$, $L_2$ are regular lang then so is $L_1\bigcup L_2$.
  2. If $L_1$, $L_2$ are regular lang then so is $L_1\circ L_2$.
  3. If $L$ is a regular lang then so is $L^*$.

Comment: I think you should add some sort of initialization i.e.  $$(\forall x\in \Sigma)(\{x\}\mbox{ is regular})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also an algebraic characterization of regular languages. 
A language $L\subset \Sigma^*$ is regular iff it exists an homomorphism (of monoids) $\phi : \Sigma^*\rightarrow M$ with $M$ a finite monoid and 
$$
L=\phi^{-1}(S)
$$ 
where $S\subset M$. You end using the formula $\phi^{-1}(\bar{S})=\overline{\phi^{-1}(S)}$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I am only allowed to use regular languages, regular expressions, languages, and their properties. So I can't use this explanation as well.

Comment: @LironIlayev: Doesn't "and their properties" in principle cover everything you might want to throw in?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Only the three mentioned are allowed to use

Comment: @HenningMakholm Is this even solveable with the terms mentioned above? Maybe some sort of induction?

Comment: @LironIlayev: One of "the three mentioned" is "and their properties". The fact that regular languages can be recognized by automata is _one of the properties of regular languages_ and is therefore, by your own definition, an allowed technique.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Alright, I see what you're saying, and I agree with you. But, I'm a uni student, and were clearly told "you are only allowed to use in the assignment what you were taught until lecture 3". That doesn't include automata or abstract alegbra, even if we know a different solution.

Comment: @LironIlayev The problem is that we do not know lecture 3. Could you be more specific ? for instance, let us know the results given in that lecture (regular grammars ? first order logic ? etc.)

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. I listed everything in the edit, if it's not possible to solve this without automata please let me know

Comment: @LironIlayev It is (as for instance my answer), but I bet, in any case, you need some further consequence of your list. I would be surprised if you could solve the problem of complements only with the first definition of regular languages.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. I understand, I will approve your answer to highlight to other users the correct answer, but I guess I will have to find a different solution to the original assigment question. Thank you

Comment: @LironIlayev Thank you for the (half-deserved) approval. I still would be curious to know a solution sticking to the definition without having to develop any "finite orbit" equivalent characterization (logic, monoidal, semigroup or the like). Let's observe what happens ...

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. I interpret your requirements as giving a proof of the closure under complement dealing only with regular expressions. But there is no such proof.

**Short answer**. Such a proof would give a proof that in any monoid, the set of rational subsets is closed under complement. However this is not true, for instance in the monoid $a^* \times \{b,c\}^*$: see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_set) for a short proof.

**Details**.

Recall that a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) is a set $M$ equipped with an associative operation (denoted multiplicatively) and an identity element $1$. Then $\mathcal{P}(M)$, the set of subsets of $M$, is equipped with an addition, the usual set union (that is $X + Y = X \cup Y$ by definition), and a product: $XY = \{xy \mid x \in X, y \in Y \}$. Finally, if $X$ is a subset of $M$, then $X^*$ is the submonoid of $M$ generated by $X$. Note that $X^* = \{1\} + X + X^2 + \cdots\ $ The set of [*rational subsets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_set) of $M$ is the smallest subset of  $\mathcal{P}(M)$ containing the singletons $\{m\}$ (for $m \in M$) and closed under the three operations sum, product and star. As you can see, in the case of a free monoid, you recover the usual notion of regular language.

By the way, the notion introduced by Gérard Duchamp in his answer also extends to any monoid: a subset $X$ of a monoid $M$ is [*recognizable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recognizable_set) if there exists a monoid morphism $\varphi$ from $M$ onto a finite monoid $F$ and a subset $P$ of $F$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(P) = X$.

Now, Kleene's theorem implies that in a free monoid, a subset is rational if and only if it is recognizable. However, this equivalence does not hold in any monoid: for instance in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\{0\}$ is rational but not recognizable.
It is more difficult to find examples for which the rational sets are not closed under intersection (and hence under complement), but an example is given in the short answer.

Comment: Thank you for clarification (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You simply take your definition of a regular language and prove the claim step by step for each type of regular expression. An expression $E$ is regular, if and only if it generates a language (a set of strings) $\mathcal L(E)$ through the use of concatenation, union and Kleene closure only. In other words:

1. $\mathcal L(\epsilon) = \{\epsilon\}$ is a regular language and $\epsilon$ the corresponding regular expression
2. $\mathcal L(\varnothing) = \emptyset$ is a regular language and *the symbol* $\varnothing$ the corresponding regular expression.
3. For every $\alpha\in\Sigma$, $\mathcal L(\alpha) = \{\alpha\}$ is a regular language and $\alpha$ the corresponding  regular expression.
4. For any two regular expressions $R$ and $S$, $\mathcal L(R + S) = \mathcal L(S) \cup \mathcal L(S)$ is a regular language and $R + S$ the corresponding regular expression.
5. For any two regular expressions $R$ and $S$, $\mathcal L(R\circ S) = \mathcal L(S) \circ \mathcal L(S)$ is a regular language and $R \circ S$ the corresponding regular expression.
6. The language $\mathcal L(R^\ast) = \mathcal L(R)^\ast$ is regular and $R^\ast$ the corresponding regular expression.

Now you just need to think what the complement $\overline{\mathcal L(\cdot)}$ of each language $\mathcal L(\cdot)$ listed above is, and find regular expressions that generate them through the function $\mathcal L$. You will need the other properties you listed. Based on the hint you were given, the most significant rule is probably $\overline{\mathcal L(\cdot)} \cap \mathcal L(\cdot) = \emptyset$...